# How exactly Android links AIDL interface and Remote Service?

Tags: java, android, service, aidl

To avoid useless answer about how to implement AIDL in your own project - I understand how to use AIDL in your own project.

What's unclear for me is how it is used in Android source code?

For example, there is IAudioService AIDL interface in android.media package.
And there is AudioService java file. And there are a lot of examples where interface is defined in IInterfaceServiceName.aidl and implementation is in InterfaceServiceName.java. So, I thought that internals of AIDL look for Service with the name without first capital I, and then use it. However, this theory was demolished by IWifiManager and WifiService.

All of this AIDL implementations, however, share one thing - they all extend IInterfaceName.Stub class. So, that means AIDL internals look for classes extending IInterfaceName.Stub? But what if there are multiple classes extending it? And those classes aren't services at all...

Or there is some Service Manager, which somehow creates Services with those AIDL implementations as Binders? If so, please direct me to this mysterious service manager.

EDIT: I've found this service manager. It is ServiceManager in package android.os. Now it's understandable why those SomethingService aren't actually services but are actually IBinders - the service manager somehow creates services with given IBinder by method add service(String, IBinder). But now confusion only becomes even worse. 
The implementation of this service also lies in somewhat strange ServiceManagerNative, which involves remote transaction with unknown IBinder. Now I'm totally lost. How then does this ServiceManager starts itself up? How are the services added by it?

Comment: try reading this http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-implementing-remote-android-services-with-aidl/

Comment: You didn't read the question first sentence, did you? I am NOT interested how to implement AIDL in my app - I know how to do it. Instead, I am trying to understand how exactly Android system services and AIDL like IWifiManager are being connected.

Comment: so you dont have any problems with sidl itself but wanr to know android internals, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I've traced down everything to native calls, but then I just lost myself in all this native calls to everything.

Comment: i dont know if it helps or not but now that you mentioned aidl the client side doesnt have to use the generated stuff it can call directly IBinder's transact() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceManager has not a random but a predefined value. It is a Service with Binder handle equal to 0. During the boot of the system ServiceManager is one of the first services that are started by the system (you can check this in `init.rc` file). Binder permits only one service to act as a name resolver.  All other services started in the system are registered with ServiceManager.

Comment: Thanks. Since there is no other answers, and comments are not that helpful, I will accept this answer as correct.

Comment: If you want you can ask additional questions, and if I manage I will try to answer.

Comment: Well, I would like to know, where can I find the aliases for all the remote services that are being connected by ServiceManager?

Answer (score 1):

IAudioService.aidl defines public methods that are visible for other processes. During compilation, from .aidl there is an interface IAudioService generated in which you can find Stub class:

```
public static abstract class Stub extends android.os.Binder implements android.media.IAudioService{
```

now the class AudioService extends this Stub

```
public class AudioService extends IAudioService.Stub implements OnFinished {
```

locations for all mentioned files, from main android folder:

```
./frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/IAudioService.aidl
./out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/src/media/java/android/media/IAudioService.java
./frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/AudioService.java
```

Comment: I did notice this is an over-a-year-old questions, but maybe somebody else will find it useful some day.